# Interpolate using fourier transform in R

Tags: r, fft

I would like to interpolate values using the fourier transform (fft). I am struggling with converting the output of fft into a format from which I can interpolate (I don't understand how to convert the complex numbers that are output by fft into something I can use). The data I would like to interpolate from is temperature data with irregular time steps, so I'd like to use fft to interpolate and then regularize the time steps. Any help is appreciated--I really haven't gotten further than what is below...

```
a<-data.frame(c(0,3,5,6,7,9,10,11,12),c(1,2,5,6,3,1,3,8,5))

ft<-fft(as.matrix(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not super familiar with the output of fft, but `print(ft)` will return a matrix that can be exported into other formats. So if you want to save it as csv, you can do

```
 matrix.ft <- print(ft)
 write.csv(matrix.ft, "output.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```